# Linear combinations of the GCD

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

How does one properly argue whether, if: $$\{s,t \in \mathbb{Z} | s \cdot a + t \cdot b = gcd(a,b)\}$$

Then there exists another pair of numbers s' and t' satisfying $$s' \cdot a + t' \cdot b = gcd(a,b)$$

I guess the question is equivalent to asking how to determine whether there exists more than one integer linear combination that can express the GCD of two numbers a and b

Comment: Of course.  There are linear combinations that add to $0$, clearly, so just add those to the combination you have.

Comment: You could add and subtract a common multiple of $a$ and $b$ on the left-hand side.

Comment: honestly I don't understand the question

Comment: @lulu - Thanks, this made good sense. Are the linear combinations adding up to zero the only ones which can be added/substracted to the original lin. comb?

Comment: Again, of course.  Just subtract one combination from the other and you obtain a combination that sums to $0$.

Comment: @Exodd sorry, maybe i was not being clear enough. The question is that if you have a linear combination satisfying $s \cdot a + t \cdot b = gcd(a,b)$. Does there exist a pair of numbers **other** than $s,t$, call them s' and t' that satifies $$s' \cdot a + t' \cdot b = gcd(a,b)$$

Comment: $s'=s+b$ and $t'=t-a$ does the trick, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that $$sa +tb=d \iff (s+kb)a+(t-ka)b=s’a+t’b=d$$